How to call `time` from python with its stderr returned only
How can I capture the output of /usr/bin/time only, if the command itself outputs stderr?
import subprocess
print(subprocess.run('/usr/bin/time -p foo', capture_output=True, shell=True).stderr.decode())

prints
foo_stderr
real 0.02
user 0.01
sys 0.00

I am aware (and not looking for answers) of the following options:

writing output to a file (e.g. GNU time --output file)
processing the captured output to filter out the relevant data


Execute foo in its own shell with its stderr redirected.
print(subprocess.run(['/usr/bin/time', '-p', 'bash', '-c', 'foo 2>/dev/null'], capture_output=True).stderr.decode())


Running bash introduces measurement error due to overhead.

True, but you can time an empty command and factor that out.

Of course, you don't have to use /usr/bin/time in the first place. Python has its own library for timing things.
